# JDBC Hive2 Kerbros Invalid status 21 error

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, java-17

First try using user group information

```
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication","Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("tp_hive_uat/abc.com@CTP.abc.com","/export/home/tps_hive_uat.abc.keytab");
System.out.println("Kerberos Connected");
String conStr = "jdbc:hive2://bigdata.abc.com:10000/ots_staging;principal=hive/bigdata.abc.com@CTP.abc.com";
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("show databases");
```

Try 2:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","/export/home/gss-jaas.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","/etc/krb5.conf");

String conStr = "jdbc:hive2://bigdata.abc.com:10000/ots_staging;principal=hive/bigdata.abc.com@CTP.abc.com";
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("show databases");
```

gss-jaas.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   useTicketCache=false
   principal="tp_hive_uat/abc.com@CTP.abc.com"
   doNotPrompt=true
   keyTab="/export/home/tps_hive_uat.abc.keytab"
   debug=true;
```

This is in executable jar and i invoke it using

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms4000m /export/home/Scheduler_V8.jar com.tp.scheduler.SchedulerMain
```

but both try is giving below exception, what i am missing?

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
> jdbc:hive2://bigdata.abc.com:10000/ots_staging;principal=hive/bigdata.abc.com@CTP.abc.com:
> Invalid status 21     at
> org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:256)
> at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)     at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
> at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
> at
> com.citi.tport.scheduler.SchedulerMain.main(SchedulerMain.java:178)
> Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid
> status 21     at
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:232)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
> at
> org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:277)